# How to show options in view based on oder

Tags: cakephp, phpmyadmin

in may view i use

```
   <option><?=__('Select Language')?>:</option>
                    <option <?= (isset($userSetting['UserSetting']) && $userSetting['UserSetting']['user_lang'] == 'eng') ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?> value="eng" >English</option>
                    <option <?= ( isset($userSetting['UserSetting']) && $userSetting['UserSetting']['user_lang'] == 'fre') ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?> value="fre">French</option>
                    <option <?= ( isset($userSetting['UserSetting']) && $userSetting['UserSetting']['user_lang'] == 'ger') ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?> value="ger">German</option>
                    <option <?= ( isset($userSetting['UserSetting']) && $userSetting['UserSetting']['user_lang'] == 'ita') ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?> value="ita">Italian</option>
```

I am using Language table and i assigned weight to each language now i want to display the above option in my view based on the weight in my languages table, what query i have to write in my view and where to get the required output....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
(isset($userSetting['UserSetting']) && $userSetting['UserSetting']['user_lang'] == 'eng') ? 'selected="selected"' : ''
```

There is a missing ')' at the end.

```
echo (isset($userSetting['UserSetting']) && $userSetting['UserSetting']['user_lang'] == 'eng' ? 'selected="selected"' : '');
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

If `UserSetting` is a model, just pass it a `order` param when you retrieve the data.

```
$userSetting = $this->UserSetting->find('all', array(
                   'order'=> array('weight'=>'DESC')
               ));
```

Then use an approriate `foreach` to output your languages. You shouldn't need to do this "manually" if the data is coming from a database.

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth are you outputting all the options manually?  Use the HtmlHelper, which is meant for this;

Inside your controller;

```
// get the languages from your database
$languages = $this->Language->find('list', array(
    'order' => array('weight' => 'desc')
));

$this->set('languages', $languages);
```

Inside your view:

```
echo $this->Form->input(
    'UserSetting.user_lang', 
    array(
         'options' => $languages,
         'empty' => __('Select language'),
    )
);
```

However, if your Model relations and primary/foreign keys are defined properly in your application, you should retrieve the languages via;

```
$languages = $this->UserSetting->Language->find('list', array(
    'order' => array('weight' => 'desc')
));
```

If the `'primaryKey'` and [`'displayField'`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#model-displayfield) properties are configures correctly in your `Language` model, this should retrieve the right key/value pairs (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list)

And the key for the FormHelper should be `UserSetting.Language`; CakePHP should then automatically find the available options from the `$languages` viewVar automatically;

```
echo $this->Form->input('UserSetting.Language', array('empty' => __('Select language')));
```

Also be sure to properly 'create' and 'close' the Form uing the FormHelper

#### Read it in the manual;

This section contains an example for saving associated data with an example on how to create a form;

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-form-elements